# Transform multiple entries in cell into new columns in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a messy dataset with multiple entries in some cells. The numbers in paranthesis refer to the specific columns "(1)", "(2)", and "(3)". In this example
[multiple entries in cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdKbK.png) 30 refers to column (2) and 20 refers to column (1). No information for column (3).
I would like to split up/extract the values in the cells and create 3 additional columns.

Several hundred cells are affected in several columns.
[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6015f.png)
In the end I would like to have 3 new columns for each column affected. Any idea how I do that? I'm still a rookie so help is much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please don't upload code, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).